# replace XMLNode in a XMLString Column of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I want to delete xmlnode `<responseDeclaration>` whose attribute "identifier" value is  not "RESPONSE" from table "Rubric"; which has column "XMLString" of type String and "XMLNode" column of type Xml.Before deleting the node `"<responseDeclaration>"` we need Outerxml of the node which I am deleting into a temp variable; which in this case is

```
 "<responseDeclaration identifier="VH182077_zone_choice_list_9.RESPONSE" baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" />"
```

Below is the content for both the columns "XMLNode" and "XMLString"

```
<assessmentItem xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2"  timeDependent="false" title="ZonesSS" toolVersion="1.0" toolName="Rubric">
  <responseDeclaration baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" identifier="RESPONSE">
    <correctResponse>
      <value>i3</value>
    </correctResponse>
  </responseDeclaration>
  <responseDeclaration identifier="VH182077_zone_choice_list_9.RESPONSE" baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" />
  <outcomeDeclaration baseType="float" cardinality="single" identifier="SCORE">
    <defaultValue>
      <value>0</value>
    </defaultValue>
  </outcomeDeclaration>
  <responseProcessing template="http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p1/rptemplates/match_correct_1.xml" />
</assessmentItem>
```

Below is the result I am looking for in both the columns. we do have these kind of records in the "Rubric" Table.

```
<assessmentItem xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2" identifier="3c6e5f58-bd87-e511-ba0c-005056a8223d" timeDependent="false" title="ZonesSS" toolVersion="1.0" toolName="IAT Rubric">
  <responseDeclaration baseType="identifier" cardinality="single" identifier="RESPONSE">
    <correctResponse>
      <value>i3</value>
    </correctResponse>
  </responseDeclaration>
  <outcomeDeclaration baseType="float" cardinality="single" identifier="SCORE">
    <defaultValue>
      <value>0</value>
    </defaultValue>
  </outcomeDeclaration>
  <responseProcessing template="http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p1/rptemplates/match_correct_1.xml" />
</assessmentItem>
```

Tried to get string value of node which i want to delete with below query; but not successful.

```
 Declare @RDNode as 
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
    ('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS ns)
   SET @RDNode= select cast(XmlString as xml).value('(/ns:assessmentItem/ns:responseDeclaration[2])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM dbo.Rubric R WHERE R.[XML].exist('(/ns:assessmentItem/ns:responseDeclaration[2]/@identifier[contains(.,".RESPONSE")])')=1
    WHERE ..
```

Tried to delete second ResponseDeclaration Node from  'XMLNode'

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS ns)
Update dbo.Rubric 
SET [XMLNode].modify('replace value of (/ns:assessmentItem/ns:responseDeclaration[2])[1] with ""')
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to delete xmlnode  whose attribute "identifier" value is not "RESPONSE"..."

Use [`delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) keyword instead of `replace value of` to delete node(s) from XML data type :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS ns)
Update dbo.Rubric
SET [XMLNode].modify('
    delete /ns:assessmentItem/ns:responseDeclaration[@identifier != "RESPONSE"]
')
```

And use `query()` method instead of `value()` to get the XML markup that will be deleted :

```
Declare @RDNode as XML
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS ns)
select @RDNode =  R.[XMLNode].query('/ns:assessmentItem/ns:responseDeclaration[@identifier != "RESPONSE"]')
FROM dbo.Rubric R 
WHERE ....
```

Comment: How we delete the namespace "xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" from above <assessmentItem>  root node.